# getting mouse position every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to get mouse coordinated on page every 3 seconds, but Event object is undefined in setInterval function.

```
function mouse() {
  console.log(window.event) // => undefined
}
setInterval(mouse, 3000)
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not respond to the `mousemove` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var m_pos_x,m_pos_y;
window.onmousemove = function(e) { m_pos_x = e.pageX;m_pos_y = e.pageY; }
setInterval(function() { console.log("x= " + m_pos_x + "y = " + m_pos_y); },3000);
```

Comment: Not a crossbrowser solution, I'd say,

Comment: Hmmm.Yes.But shouldn't broswers interpret javascript the same way?I know that problems existed before,but now we are 2011.Something must have surely been done to solve that "crossbroswer" problems!

Comment: @Aleksander: there's a large gap between what browsers should do and what they actually do. Even in 2011. It's like real life, actually.

Comment: Thank you!! This got me in the correct direction. Been stumbling on this for about 40 min now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hook the mousemove event and record where it is every time it moves.  If you don't get a mouse moveevent, then it hasn't moved or isn't in your window.