# How to calculate a path to the mouse?

Tags: javascript

I have virual world:

```
var worldSize = [10000, 10000]; //width, height
```

Next I have player's position:

```
var currentPlayerPosition = [5000, 5000]; //center on the map
```

[image]

**Now I need every 10ms check current mouse position, and calculate direction to mouse, and update `currentPlayerPosition` to direction result -1px (or +1px if mouse is under player...)**. The same as right/left side.

**Edit**: I dont need code, I need mathematica to calculate direction and then substract/add pixels to array of player's position `[5000,5000]`

**Edit 2**

Example what I mean:

If `currentPlayerPosition` is `[5000,5000]` and `mousePosition` is `[4500,4800]` then what I must math from `currentPlayerPosition` every 10ms if I want move player to mouse position?

```
currentPlayerPosition[0] = currentPlayerPosition[0]-(what_number_here)
currentPlayerPosition[1] = currentPlayerPosition[1]-(what_number_here)
```

or

```
currentPlayerPosition[0] = currentPlayerPosition[0]+(what_number_here)
currentPlayerPosition[1] = currentPlayerPosition[1]+(what_number_here)
```

**Edit 3**

I want make this question better so I write here my (bad) idea:

I tried first calculate distance X and Y:

```
var fullWidth = 5000;
var playerPositionX = 2500;
var mousePositionX = 2700;
var distanceBetweenX = mousePositionX-playerPositionX; //200
```

Next, the same code I tried calculate Y distance. I got results like this:

```
distanceBetweenX = 200;
distanceBetweenY = 150;
```

Now I tried every 1000ms deduct -1px from both sides X and Y. But this is not solve my problem because 150 is less than 200, so line with this is like

[image]

And that's bad.

I think now is this question good and I believe my ban for asking will be removed. Thank you guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726409/getting-mouse-position-every-3-seconds Check this.

Comment: Moving the player exactly 1 pixel left/right and up/down depending on the cursor position is going to result in the character moving first exactly 45 degrees to some direction and then directly left/right or up/down towards the cursor, instead of moving towards the cursor following the shortest path.

Comment: I need only calculating function example how I can subtract or add pixels to current player's position to mouse direction

Comment: @Dave as yoy may have noticed - I saw your question on gamedev, I hope my answer here is useful.

Comment: @Theraot yes i'm reading but dont know what is that Norm() and sqrt(). I need it in javascript :-)

Comment: @Dave Javascript standard library includes [Math.sqrt](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt.html) it is defined as the positive value of the square root of the parameter. Norm is length of the vector, javascript doesn't include that but you can implement it with sqrt - just do [pythagoras theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Other_forms_of_the_theorem).

Comment: @mplungjan I updated my question. If is it still bad, tell me please what more can I do

Comment: @mplungjan Im talking about `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`. Trying update my question best how I know..

Comment: Perhaps you can flag or post in meta?

Comment: I tried flag it. I try update my other questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Vectors!

Forget the equation of the line, slope and intercept won't buy you much in game development. Use Vectors!

So, you have two points

```
player: (700, 250)
mouse: (800, 100)
```

And you want the vector from one to the other. That's the [difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDifference.html):

```
Difference: player - mouse
=>
Difference: (700, 250) - (800, 100)
=>
Difference: (700 - 800, 250 - 100)
=>
Difference: (-100, 150)
```

Errata: since you will be moving player with the code (and not the mouse), we need the distance from player to mouse, so calculate `mouse - player` instead. This is because we will add the (manipulated) difference vector to the player vector later.

---

For abstract what you do next is calculate the norm and the unit vector. Then - probably - use scale the unit vector to get an advance vector to add to the position.

---

### Euclidean geometry

Ok, now, how long is that vector? That's the [norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html) of the vector:

```
Distance: Norm(Difference)
=>
Distance: Norm((-100, 150))
=>
Distance: sqrt((-100 * -100) + (150 * 150))
=>
Distance: 180.277563...
```

Note: that's [Euclidean distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanMetric.html) (a.k.a. Pythagoras theorem, *generalized for more than 2D, but we are in 2D anyway*).

What direction is it? Well, it is negative 100 on the horizontal and 150 on the vertical... So, it is on the Quadrant 2.

We can represent the direction as the unit vector of the difference (that is a vector of the same direction and length 1):

```
Direction: Difference/Distance
=>
Direction: (-100, 150)/180.277563...
=>
Direction: (-100 / 180.277563..., 150 / 180.277563...)
=>
Direction: (-0.554700..., 0.832050...)
```

It may be harder to make sense of the values of unit vector. Just remember that the unit vector keeps the same direction.

The reason why the unit vector is useful is because then you can scale it to whatever distance you need. For example if you want to move 10 distance units you [scale](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarMultiplication.html) the unit vector by 10 and that is the value you have to [add](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) to the position.

So the advance vector would be the unit vector multiplied by the distance you want to advance.

---

I'll talk about the slope a bit for ease of understanding, what you do to calculate the [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) is as follows:

```
Slope: Y/X
=>
Slope: 150/-100
=>
Slope: -1.5
```

The slope as you can see is the rate of change of the Y over the X (that is, how much does the Y change for each unit of X). So -1.5 means that for each unit you advance on the X axis you move -1.5 units on the Y axis... that's the direction.

You may prefer an angle:

```
Angle: Atan(Slope)
=>
Angle: Atan(-1.5)
=>
Angle: -0.982794...
```

Note 1: that value is in [radians](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radian.html). You can covert it to degrees if you want.

When implementing use Atan2 if available in the standard library of your language. It will take the X and Y values and will work around what would have been a division by 0 calculating the slope. Edit: futhermore, if you use Atan the angle will be on the first or fourth quadrant. To understand this consider that -1/2 and 1/-2 are the same slope, but (2, -1) and  (-2, 1) aren't the same vector (they aren't the on same direction either).

So, use Atan2 instead:

```
Angle: Atan2(Difference)
=>
Angle: Atan2(Y, X)
=>
Angle: Atan2(150, -100)
=>
Angle: 2.158798...
```

Compare:

```
-0.982794 radian = -56.3099° (degrees) [Quadrant 4]
2.158798 radian = 123.69° (degrees) [Quadrant 2]
```

The angle isn't of much use in the implementation actually. You will find yourself working with the unit vector as explained above.

---

### Manhattan geometry

Manhattan geometry (a.k.a. Taxicab geometry) is a geometry in which things only move along the axis. So you don't really have diagonals or varied angles. Just up, down, left and right (in 2D, that is).

If you are working in Manhattan geometry you calculate the norm as follows:

```
Distance: Norm(Difference)
=>
Distance: Norm((-100, 150))
=>
Distance: abs(-100) + abs(150)
=>
Distance: 250
```

That is by adding the absolute values of the length of the vector along each axis. The reason is that the object will have to move on one axis and then the other.

Now, the unit vector is rarely used when implementing a game in Manhattan geometry. Instead what you may do is take the absolute values to decide over what axis to move first. The axis on which the vector has more absolute value should move first (or last, depending on what you want).

Alternatively you may move first always on the same axis and then the other. It is trickier to test when the destination has been reached on a single axis, it requires to check the distance per axis independently - and will run into the oscillation problem described below, plus the problem of comparing floating point numbers.

So, the advance vector would be the distance you want to move (with the sign of the difference vector) over the axis you decided to move first and 0 on the other axis.

---

### Speed

You are checking the position at fixed intervals - although it is worth to measure the time passed from the last check, because computer performance may vary - meaning that you have the time.

Say, if you want to move 10 distance units per unit of time, but that time that passed is actually 3 units. Then the distance is 3 * 10 = 30 units. And that is what you use to scale the advance vector.

Regardless, what is actually happening is that the object is jumping from a position to the other, as you update the position. This will have a probably unexpected consequence: the object will inevitably overshoot. It will go beyond the target point and then try to go back and then go beyond again, oscillating back and forth... to prevent this you will check if the norm of the distance vector is less than the distance you will advance, and if it is less... just put the object at the destination.

Please note that if you want flock behaviors, collision detection, acceleration, etc. This part of the code will need to be updated.

---

**A note on screen coordinates**: For [historical reasons](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/83571/10408) the computers place the coordinate’s origin on the top left corner. So when you have a positive value on the horizontal axis, it is going to the right. And a positive value on the vertical axis, it is going downwards. Unless you are working under a transformed coordinate system... in which case it is whatever the transformation says, in doubt, do experiment.

### Working example

```js
var time = (new Date()).getTime(); // time in milliseconds

var player_element = document.getElementById('player');
player_element.style.left = 0;
player_element.style.top = 0;

var mouse = [0, 0]; // pixels
var player = [0, 0]; // pixels
var speed = 100.0; // pixels per second

// get the mouse pointer position
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
      // update mouse
      mouse[0] = e.pageX;
      mouse[1] = e.pageY;
   }); 
});

function update()
{
  // calculate the difference
  let diff = [mouse[0] - player[0], mouse[1] - player[1]];
  // calculate the norm
  let norm = Math.sqrt(diff[0] * diff[0] + diff[1] * diff[1]);
  if (norm == 0)
  {
    // already at target or not yet initilized
    return;
  }
  // calculate the unit vector
  let unit = [diff[0] / norm, diff[1] / norm];
  
  // get elapsed time from last iteration
  // divided by 1000 to get seconds
  let new_time = (new Date()).getTime();
  let elapsed = (new_time - time) / 1000.0;
  
  // calculate advance by scaling unit vector
  let advance = [unit[0] * elapsed * speed, unit[1] * elapsed * speed];
  
  // calculate the norm of the advance vector
  let advance_norm = Math.sqrt(advance[0] * advance[0] + advance[1] * advance[1]);
  
  // check if we are about to overshoot
  if (advance_norm > norm)
  {
    // we are too close to target
    // just set the position to the target
    player[0] = mouse[0];
    player[1] = mouse[1];
  }
  else
  {
    // there is still room to go
    // advance
    player[0] += advance[0];
    player[1] += advance[1];
  }
  // update player and time
  player_element.style.left = (player[0]) + "px";
  player_element.style.top = (player[1]) + "px";
  time = new_time;
}

setInterval(update, 40);
```

```css
#player
{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  background: green;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I try edit it and add world like my question and moving canvas. Thank you for awesome code example!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to calculate the equation of the line that crosses these 2 points. You can find an example [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) or follow these instructions:

Given 2 points, A and B:

- finding the slope m = difference in y / difference in x = (yA - yB) / (xA - xB)
- compute the equation using the slope => y - y1 = m(x - x1)

Considering that you want to move the player in the right direction, you only need the slope. The entire equation is useful if you plan to plot the line.

Comment: Can you post example if my mouse is for example at 4000x4000 on the map? (-1000 and -1000 from player)

Comment: @Dave :

A(3000, 3000) - player
B(4000, 4000) - mouse
Slope = (3000 - 4000) / (3000 - 4000) = 1 (as expected, given the coordinates)
Equation => y - 3000 = 1(x - 3000) => y - 3000 = x - 3000 => y = x or f(x) = x 
Note: slope = 1 means that for every pixel moved on Ox you must also move by 1 pixel on Oy

Comment: Thank you again. I tried it with random numbers and my result is `0,875`. What direction is it? up? down? left? right? How many pixels from this number I must subtract/add to player's current position from top and left? I used `((2500 - 3000) - 3000) / ((7000 - 8000) - 3000)`.